# What is the use of begin in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I don't understand how using the `begin` keyword is useful in writing a sequence of expressions in Scheme.

I mean, when I write expressions, aren't they supposed to be evaluated from left to right? So, why must I still include a `begin` keyword?

I read that `begin` is supposed to eliminate side-effects from input and output. Can anyone give me a situation where begin is necessary?

Comment: When writing a function `begin` is always added behind the scene. `begin` evaluates the following forms in order of appearance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`begin` is necessary every time you need several forms when the syntax allows only one form. For instance, if you need to increment a variable `y` each time you use it:

```
(+ x 
   (begin (set! y (+ y 1)) y) 
   z)
```

If you omit the begin, then you simply could not write this expression (in Common Lisp, the same expression could be written as `(+ x (incf y) z)`).

Note that `(set! x y)` does not return a value. This is the reason we need to use `begin`, since `(begin f1 f2 ... fn)` evaluates `f1 ... fn` in turn and then returns the value of `fn`. So, `(begin (set! y (+ y 1)) y)` increments the value of `y` and the `y` is evaluated, and then its new value is returned.

`begin` is normally used when there is some side-effect.

Comment: "If you omit the begin, then you simply could not write this expression". You can actually write that expression using lambda: `(+ x ((lambda (x) y) (set! y (+ y 1))) z)`. In fact, `begin` can be defined in terms of lambda: `(begin exp1) --> exp1` and `(begin exp1 exp2 ...) --> ((lambda (x) (begin exp2 ...)) exp1)`.